# How / when to release the resources acquired by viewHolder in a recyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer, android-lifecycle

To be simple, I have a recyclerView which has viewHolders holding MediaPlayer instances. When users close that activity, I want to release the resources aquired by MediaPlayer instance. But unlike onCreateViewHolder, I couldn't find any onDestroyViewHolder methods. My viewHolder implementation looks like this:

```
class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    private val mMediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
    
    internal fun onBind(model: Model) {
        if(model.contentType == "Audio") {
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mPreparedListener);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mContext, uri, null)
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync()
            // do other stuff

        } else if(mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.reset()
            mMediaPlayer.release()
            mMediaPlayer = null
        }
    }
}
```

I know the Adapter class has onViewDetachedFromWindow method. But I am not sure whether that can fit here. Can someone tell me a solution for this?

Comment: _"I have a recyclerView which has viewHolders holding mediaPlayer instances"_. This is a very wrong way to organise your code. This kind of resources should be held by `Activity`/`Fragment`.

Comment: @Onik, For example, in a chat app (which is what i am trying to build), user can share media. So that will be displayed and played in the chat thread. If cannot play audio in recyclerview, how handle this situation? Is there any workaround for this scenario?

Comment: MediaPlayer is not a UI component and should therefore not be stored in a UI component. I don't work with audio much, but my first instinct says to keep a single MediaPlayer instance available in your Fragment, create a function for setting a new data source and playing it, and call that function from your UI components in the Adapter.

Comment: @Tenfour04, Yeah, I got your point. Even I felt same when I encountered this situation. But messenger apps like facebook/whatsapp can instantly play the audio when we press the play button even when there are multiple audio in same view. If it is storing MediaPlayer instance in Fragment/Activity, then it must be having a list of mediaPlayers, each in prepared state, having urls for all the different audiotracks visible in the view. Can this be the case? Is this a better solution? Any other idea?

Comment: That sounds like a potential solution, creating a MediaPlayerPool class so you can independently control how many sounds are preloaded at a time. You could give it a limit. So as views come on the screen they submit their sound Uri to the Pool and it can call `prepare()` on it with the next available MediaPlayer, replacing the oldest if it's at the limit. You might want to give it a dedicated Handler for processing these requests so it can do it in the background off the UI thread and keep the `prepare()` and `start()` calls in order.

Comment: The media player must be on the fragment/activity and when the adapter row is clicked then you pass the source of the media with a callback. Whatever is on the adapter row is just a view, if there is a stop/play button or progress bar all that is updated by updating the underlying data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create method to *releaseResources* in your viewHolder and call it from *onViewRecycled* which is overriden in your recycler adapter

```
    override fun onViewRecycled(holder: MediaViewHolder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder)
        val videoItem = mediaItems.getOrNull(holder.bindingAdapterPosition)
        holder.releasePlayer(videoItem)
    }
```

in order to get this method called each time your fragment goes to stop state you should set recyclerview adapter to null

```
  override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        currentPage = binding.pager.currentItem
        binding.pager.adapter = null
  }
```

this will cause onViewRecycled to be called on all viewHolders

and you should set adapter back on recyclerview in onStart()

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    if (binding.pager.adapter == null) {
        binding.pager.adapter = adapter
        binding.pager.setCurrentItem(currentPage, false)
    }
}
```

this example is on ViewPager2 but this works with RecyclerView also.